# App with SQLite crashes for unknown reason

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have some issues with an app. I wanted to implement SQLite to learn how it works so I put it in a simple quiz app. I used one of the online tutorials as a base. Unfortunately, it crashes for a reason I cannot understand because it's the first time I'm using SQLite...

It crashes in the menu right after I tap on the button which starts the new game activity.

Error from the Android Studio:

```
06-29 18:23:32.986 25997-25997/com.example.wojciech.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.wojciech.myapplication, PID: 25997
                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wojciech.myapplication/com.example.wojciech.myapplication.nowa_g}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CREATE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CREATE TABLE bazaPytan(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,question TEXT,choice1 TEXT, choice2 TEXT, choice3 TEXT, answer TEXT);
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                                                                                     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CREATE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CREATE TABLE bazaPytan(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,question TEXT,choice1 TEXT, choice2 TEXT, choice3 TEXT, answer TEXT);
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:893)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:504)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:726)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1784)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1715)
                                                                                        at com.example.wojciech.myapplication.BazaDanychSQLite.onUpgrade(BazaDanychSQLite.java:44)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:256)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
                                                                                        at com.example.wojciech.myapplication.BazaDanychSQLite.getAllQuestionsList(BazaDanychSQLite.java:63)
                                                                                        at com.example.wojciech.myapplication.QuestionBank.initQuestions(QuestionBank.java:31)
                                                                                        at com.example.wojciech.myapplication.nowa_g.onCreate(nowa_g.java:42)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Activity of the game:

```
package com.example.wojciech.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class nowa_g extends AppCompatActivity {

    private QuestionBank mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionBank();
    private TextView Wynik; //score
    private TextView WidokPytan; //view of a question
   // private TextView zespol;
    //private TextView album;
    private Button wybor1; //choice1,2 etc...
    private Button wybor2;
    private Button wybor3;

    private String odpowiedz;
    private int score = 0;
    private int numberOfQuestions = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nowa_g);
        Wynik = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wynik);
        WidokPytan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);
        wybor1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        wybor2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        wybor3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        //zespol = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zespol);
       // album = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.album);

        mQuestionLibrary.initQuestions(getApplicationContext());
        newQuestion();
        newScore(score);
    }
    private void newQuestion() {
        if (numberOfQuestions < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
            WidokPytan.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(numberOfQuestions));
            wybor1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(numberOfQuestions, 1));
            wybor2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(numberOfQuestions, 2));
            wybor3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(numberOfQuestions, 3));
            // zespol.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getZespol(numberOfQuestions));
            // album.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getAlbum(numberOfQuestions));

            odpowiedz = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(numberOfQuestions);
            numberOfQuestions++;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(nowa_g.this, "To było ostatnie pytanie!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(nowa_g.this, NajwyzszyWynik.class);
            i.putExtra("score", score);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
    private void newScore(int punkt) {
        Wynik.setText(score);
    }
    public void onClick(View view){
        Button answer = (Button) view;
        if(answer.getText().equals(odpowiedz)){
            score = score + 1;
            Toast.makeText(nowa_g.this,"Dobra odpowiedź!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //correct answer
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(nowa_g.this,"Zła odpowiedź!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //wrong answer
        }
        newScore(score);
        newQuestion();
    }
}
```

Database helper

```
package com.example.wojciech.myapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class BazaDanychSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static String DATABASE_QUESTION = "pytania.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    public static final String TABLE_QUESTION = "bazaPytan";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String QUESTION = "question";
    public static final String CHOICE1 = "choice1";
    public static final String CHOICE2 = "choice2";
    public static final String CHOICE3 = "choice3";
    public static final String ANSWER = "answer";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_QUESTION + "(" + KEY_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + QUESTION + " TEXT,"
            + CHOICE1 + " TEXT, " + CHOICE2 + " TEXT, " + CHOICE3 + " TEXT, "
            + ANSWER + " TEXT);";


    public BazaDanychSQLite(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_QUESTION, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public long addInitialQuestion (Question question){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(QUESTION, question.getQuestion());
        values.put(CHOICE1, question.getChoice(0));
        values.put(CHOICE2, question.getChoice(1));
        values.put(CHOICE3, question.getChoice(2));
        values.put(ANSWER, question.getAnswer());
        long insert = db.insert(TABLE_QUESTION, null, values);
        return insert;
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestionsList() {
        List<Question> questionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUESTION;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all records and adding to the list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question question = new Question();

                String questText= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QUESTION));
                question.setQuestion(questText);

                String choice1Text= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CHOICE1));
                question.setChoice(0,choice1Text);

                String choice2Text= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CHOICE2));
                question.setChoice(1,choice2Text);

                String choice3Text= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CHOICE3));
                question.setChoice(2,choice3Text);

                String answerText= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ANSWER));
                question.setAnswer(answerText);

                // adding to Questions list
                questionArrayList.add(question);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            Collections.shuffle(questionArrayList);
        }
        return questionArrayList;
    }

}
```

Question bank:

```
public class QuestionBank {

    List <Question> list = new ArrayList<>();
    BazaDanychSQLite myDataBaseHelper;

    public int getLength(){
        return list.size();
    }

    public String getQuestion(int a) {
        return list.get(a).getQuestion();
    }
    public String getChoice(int index, int num) {
        return list.get(index).getChoice(num-1);
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswer(int a) {
        return list.get(a).getAnswer();
    }



    public void initQuestions(Context context) {
        myDataBaseHelper = new BazaDanychSQLite(context);
        list = myDataBaseHelper.getAllQuestionsList();

        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            myDataBaseHelper.addInitialQuestion(new Question("Seems like everybody's got a _____",
                    new String[]{"price", "prince", "quack"}, "price"));
            myDataBaseHelper.addInitialQuestion(new Question("We don't need your ____, ____, ____\n",
                    new String[]{"money", "honey", "quack"}, "money"));
            myDataBaseHelper.addInitialQuestion(new Question("We just wanna make the world _____",
                    new String[]{"dance", "quack", "spin"}, "dance"));

            list = myDataBaseHelper.getAllQuestionsList();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `... crashes for unknown reason` ?! Did you read this line? `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CREATE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CREATE TABLE bazaPytan(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,question TEXT,choice1 TEXT, choice2 TEXT, choice3 TEXT, answer TEXT);` Why on Earth are you attaching a **CREATE TABLE** command to a **DELETE** one?

Comment: Well, it's the first time I'm using SQLite which I stated in the description. Secondly, that was the code provided with the tutorial.

Comment: No, it wasn't. I'm totally sure. Because it would never work.

Comment: It was, I basically CTRL+C and CTRL+V that tutorial.

Comment: So you failed to copy-paste

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81FLyzhROiQ&t=868s
Tutorial I used. Code is in one of the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION);
```

with:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bazaPytan");
```

`CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION` is not `bazaPytan`. `CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION` is the full `CREATE TABLE` statement, which does not belong as part of a `DROP TABLE` statement.

Comment: Isnt it `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bazaPytan;"+CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION);` to drop table if it exists and then recreate it..?

Comment: @Lal: The `onUpgrade()` method in the question chains to `onCreate()`, which handles the `CREATE TABLE` statement. `onUpgrade()` just needs the `DROP TABLE` statement.

Comment: Well, now the error message says something about an old question I edited in QuestionBank which isn't even in the code.

'06-29 18:57:58.844 5924-5924/com.example.wojciech.myapplication E/SQLiteLog: (1) table bazaPytan has no column named choice3'

Comment: @WojciechMiśta Try running your app after you uninstall the application.

Comment: I did
'06-29 19:09:53.249 1439-19991/? E/linker: readlink('/proc/self/fd/423') failed: Permission denied [fd=423]'
and
'                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wojciech.myapplication/com.example.wojciech.myapplication.nowa_g}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0'